# Javascript Filterable option not working for Kendo Grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

So I have this unusual situation, where 3 of the Filter options display information correctly, but the fourth one doesn't? and im not sure why. also, on the bottom right, where the total # of rows displays, it will display as "Nan - 2" or "Nan - 8", instead of "1-8 - 8"

The option that doesn't work is Case 1.

Here is the code:

```
function changeProcessedItemFilter() {
        var val = $("#processedItemFilter").prop("value");
        var grid = $("#PLAGridMain").getKendoGrid();

        var parsedValue = parseInt(val);

        var approveBtn = $("#Approve").data("kendoButton");
        var updateBtn = $("#Update").data("kendoButton");

        switch(parsedValue)
        {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1: //filter New Data only. Unprocessed/ UnSent.
                approveBtn.enable(true);
                updateBtn.enable(false);

                grid.dataSource.query({
                    filter: [{ field: "Processed", operator: "eq", value: false }, { field: "Sent", operator: "eq", value: false }]
                });
                break;
            case 2: //filter Processed/ Unsent Records.
                approveBtn.enable(false);
                updateBtn.enable(true);

                grid.dataSource.query({
                    filter: [{ field: "Processed", operator: "eq", value: true }, { field: "Sent", operator: "eq", value: false }]
                });


                break;
            case 3:// Filter GMCC Records. UnProcessed/Sent.
                approveBtn.enable(true);
                updateBtn.enable(true);

                grid.dataSource.query({
                    filter: [{ field: "Processed", operator: "eq", value: false }, { field: "Sent", operator: "eq", value: true }]
                });

                break;
            case 4:// Filter Updated Records. Processed/Sent.
                approveBtn.enable(false);
                updateBtn.enable(true);
                grid.dataSource.query({
                    filter: [{ field: "Processed", operator: "eq", value: true }, { field: "Sent", operator: "eq", value: true }]
                });
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is your `DataSource` defined?

Comment: Hey, sorry I got it working, Instead of using Kendo's Filters, I filtered it from the Controller's Method, and everything worked fine. :) Thanks.